# Change FileHelpers EOL Character

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I'm trying to parse 10GB of .dat files into something recognizable in .NET.  The column delimiter is a '~' and the EOL is a '++EOL++'.  I know how to handle the delimiter but I can't find an easy way to handle the '++EOL++' when there are no actual line breaks in the file.  Can this be handled with an option in FileHelpers or would I have to write something custom?

Comment: +1 Good question, there doesn't appear to be anything obvious in the source code that would help your problem (I probably missed something). As a quick and dirty solution you could just so a string replace.

Comment: This was always in my mind, but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something that was built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No FileHelpers does not support files with unusual end-of-lines character sequences by default.

It would probably be easiest to pre-parse the file and replace the EOL sequences.  However, it is an extensible library, so you could create your own [DataStorage subclass](http://www.filehelpers.com/FileHelpers.DataLink.DataStorage.html).  You would essentially have to override

```
public override object[] ExtractRecords()
{
    using (MyStreamReader reader = new MyStreamReader(fileName, base.mEncoding, true, 102400))
    {
        T[] localArray = this.ReadStream(reader, maxRecords);
        reader.Close();
        return localArray;
    }
}
```

and then create a new class MyStreamReader, which would be identical to the (unfortunately `sealed`) `InternalStreamReader` except for `ReadLine` which contains the EOL code

```
switch (ch)
{
    case '\n':
    case '\r':

    etc...
}
```

(By the way I'm referring to the source code for FileHelpers 2.9.9.  Version 2.0.0 seems to use a `System.IO.StreamReader` so you can just subclass it instead of duplicating `InternalStreamReader`.